# Selenium - mixing checkboxes at one page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to prepare a testcode for a web UI using Java Selenium.

I am preparing scenario for it and cannot resolve a problem how to "mix" elements.

For example let's assume that I have four radio buttons that can be chosen.

User can mark just one but also all of these buttons. 
Additionally there is a drop down list in which user can choose only one option. 
That gives us a lot of cases to test and I assume that there is smarter way than rewriting code for all of these cases.

What should I do to prepare a smart code for all of these scenarios?

Comment: I can strongly recommend to not shortcut tests. I know that testing is boring and time consuming most of the day, but writing a single test for each possible scenario is the only way to detect misbehaviour in your tested software properly. Please believe me as I'm doing this for 3 years now and I did already make some bad experiences by being lazy.

Comment: prepare a data file, each data row represents one data scenario, change  code in function to input each data field, to handle situation:  several values in one data field to choose more than one radio button, etc.  Run loop on the rows of data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one hand, you can use a data-driven test approach to test all of the combinations. The exact details on how to do it depends on the testing framework you're using (e.g. junit, testng, etc.). You can probably do it either using an external file like @yong suggested or using parameters in the test method.
However, the combinations of the input fields is only part of the equation. The question you have to ask yourself is what the test should verify and what's the expected result for each combination. If the expected results of all combinations differ from one another only by something that can be expressed as a single value, then you can add this value to each row in the dataset. But if each combination affects the SUT in a different way then you'd probably need a separate test for each of them. You may use the builder design pattern to avoid duplicating the technical details (of selecting the values) between the tests, but the tests themselves need to be different.
Note that unlike manual tests where you often just know what to expect and what's not even if it's not specified explicitly, in automated tests you must be very explicit about the expected results of each test.